# Unexpected scope for $(this) in jQuery using each and function

Tags: jquery, scope

When i execute the following code, i'd expect the same element id to be alerted twice but instead, the first one is correct while the second always show the name of the first element in the set.

```
$("div.someClass").each(function (index) {
  $(this).click(function () {
    alert($(this).attr("id")); // Here i get the actually clicked element
    $.when($("div.someClass").animate({ }, 0)).then(function () {
      alert($(this).attr("id")); // Here i get the first element in of that class
    });
  });
});
```

Why is it so? How to resolve it? I have tried passing the name of the element into the function but it didn't work.

Comment: When you click on one div, you want all of them with the same class to animate? You are re-selecting the divs in `$.when` and since the `.then` callback is only called once you are grabbing the id attribute of the first item in the collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save the `$(this)` in some variable for instance `that` and later use in `animate`

```
$("div.someClass").each(function (index) {
  $(this).click(function () {
    alert($(this).attr("id")); // Here i get the actually clicked element
    var that = $(this);
    $.when($("div.someClass").animate({ }, 0)).then(function () {           
      alert(that.attr("id")); // Here i get the first element in of that class
      alert($(this).attr("id")); 
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The value of `this` is automatically altered on every function call.  So, unless multiple function calls conspire to purposely preserve a particular value of `this` by passing it in and then using `.apply()` or `.call()` to set it before calling your callback, it will be different.  Javascript goes by these rules:

- If you make a method call, the value of `this` is set to the object whose method it is.
- If you make a normal function call, `this` is set to the global object (normally `window`).
- If you use `fn.apply()` or `fn.call()`, then `this` is set based on the first argument.

The simplest solution is to save the value of `this` in a local variable and then refer to that.

```
$("div.someClass").each(function (index) {
  var self = $(this);
  self.click(function () {
    alert(self.attr("id")); // Here i get the actually clicked element
    $.when($("div.someClass").animate({ }, 0)).then(function () {
      alert(self.attr("id")); // Here i get the first element in of that class
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to access the element of the each function: http://api.jquery.com/each/

```
$("div.someClass").each(function (index, element) {
  $(element).click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    alert($this.attr("id")); // Here i get the actually clicked element
    $.when($("div.someClass").animate({ }, 0)).then(function () {
      alert($this.attr("id")); // Here i get the first element in of that class
    });
  });
});
```

Also helps to read up on what "this" means: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this
jQuery can confuse your understanding of what "this" is supposed to be with all the context changing it does for event handling.